# How do I open this window in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I was in this window earlier changing some settings, need to get back to it but cannot for the life of me find how to navigate to it.

Comment: Right-click your project and hit the Properties menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the Project Properties - Go to Project -> "ProjectName" Properties. There you can see that window you are showing